# Error in standard deviation and variance from error in data

Tags: measurement-error, error-propagation

I have a set of datapoints $x_i$ which have known upper bounds for absolute errors $\delta x_i$. (To clarify, this means each $x_i$ is actually $x_{i_0} \pm \delta x_i$). For simplicity, assume that all the errors are equal, i.e., $\delta x_i = \delta x$ $\forall x_i$.

The statistics of the datapoints is expected to fit a Gaussian. In other words, if one plots a histogram of the datapoints $x_i$, the histogram would fit a Gaussian reasonably well. Assume the mean of this Gaussian is zero.

How does one quantify the error in the standard deviation and variance of this Gaussian given the individual errors of the datapoints $x_i$ as described above?

Note that I'm interested in the computing the error associated with the SD and variance, and not the SD and variance themselves.

Comment: When you say "the errors are all equal" do you mean that they have the same value (which $\delta x_i = \delta x$ would imply but which seems a bizarre thing to have), or do you mean that they're of the same average magnitude in some sense?

Comment: @Glen_b, yes. I am implying that the magnitude of error of all datapoints is nearly constant. Sorry for the confusion, the quantities $\delta x_i$ are positive.

Comment: Do you mean, say $E(\delta x_i)=\delta_x$? or something else?

Comment: @Glen_b yes. Precisely that.